# Changing family of many metas

Tags: workflow, meta-objects

I've got a few hundred meta balls making up an object. I'd like to duplicate it, and convert it to a mesh.

It seems that the duplicated metas end up being in the same family as the originals, so *everything* gets converted to mesh.

Is there any way to duplicate a bunch of metas, and convert them to a new meta family?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Metas/Editing#Object_Families) the family of a meta is defined by its name. Since the names of objects in Blender are automatically generated when duplicating them I don't think it is possible to copy metas into a new family.

There might however be a workaround for what you are trying to do: Select all your metas and copy them to a buffer by pressing [Ctrl+C]. Then convert the metas to a mesh. If you now press [Ctrl+V] the previous metas will be pasted from the buffer and you have your mesh and your metas.